# Put char into array by using pointer in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I have a problem, they gave me a task. They told us that we must use a pointer to put the value from the keyboard to array and then print that array.

I try to create that, but I don't know why this is wrong. I define my array then I get value and put that value into an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10000 // Maximum array size


int main ()
{
    char keyboardArray[N];    
    char *r;            
    r = keyboardArray;
    while( (*r++ = getchar()) != EOF );
    printf("You write %s", r);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. At the end of the loop, `r` points to the end of the string, not the beginning. So printing `r` won't print the string that was entered. You should print the `keyboardArray` rather than `r`.
2. You're never adding a null terminator to the string, so you can't use the `%s` format operator.
3. `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char` -- this is needed to be able to distinguish `EOF` from ordinary characters. So you need to read into a different variable before storing into the array.

```
int main ()
{
    char keyboardArray[N];    
    char *r;    
    int c;        
    r = keyboardArray;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        *r++ = c;
    }
    *r = '\0'; // Add null terminator
    printf("You write %s\n", keyboardArray);
}
```

Note that this will read until EOF, so the user will have to type a special character like <kbd>Control-d</kbd> (on Unix) or <kbd>Control-z</kbd> (on Windows) to end the input. You might want to check for newline as well, so they can enter a single line:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
```

Comment: Make that `while (r < keyboardArray + N - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`. Always, **always**, ***always*** check for buffer overflow in C!

Comment: I know this is a beginner question, but it is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in any case you need an intermediate variable that will accept a read character.

Also you need to append the entered sequence of characters with the terminating zero.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10000 // Maximum array size

int main( void )
{
    char keyboardArray[N];    
    char *r = keyboardArray;

    for ( int c; 
          r + 1 < keyboardArray + N && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n';
          ++r )
    {
        *r = c;
    }

    *r = '\0';

    printf( "You write %s\n", keyboardArray );
}
```